# Java Runtime.exec() removes newlines from arguments

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I have a Java class that is using `Runtime.exec()` to execute a `cscript` process with one  `String` of several arguments that is retrieved from a database.  One of these arguments includes newline characters that need to be preserved, but `Runtime.exec()` removes the newline characters.  The problem doesn't exist when using `ProcessBuilder`, but I'd rather not have to worry about parsing my list of arguments.

Is there a way to preserve the newlines when calling `exec()`?

In case anyone wants to see it, here's a simplified example of the call to `exec()`:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript test.vbs \"line1\r\nline2\"");
```

My script was getting "line1 line2" as one argument with the newline replaced by a space.

Comment: Can you post the relevant section(s) of code?  It's possible that "Runtime.exec" has platform dependent behavior...

Comment: In windows I can't really imagine a case where a newline would be valid in a program's command line and therefore I wouldn't be surprised if the ability to pass one broke programs.  How would you pass that argument correctly from the command line or a batch file?

Comment: Hard to guess what's wrong based on the scant information provided. Please tell more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is little information in your question but I'm wildly guessing that your issue is as follows.

Note that the forms of [`Runtime.exec(...)` with a String command argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.io.File%29) will end up using a [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to generate the actual command tokens, which might explain the unexpected removal of newline characters.  Try using a form of [`Runtime.exec(...)` with a *String array* command argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) so that no parsing of the string command arguments occurs.

Of course, doing so might require you to parse the arguments yourself but that might be the only way to ensure that the program does what you expect.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  The StringTokenizer includes the newline character as a delimiter by default, so that is why the newlines aren't sent to my script.

Comment: Good guess for a poorly presented question by @Worf. 1+ up-vote.